# NGINX on LAN-Server: access by domain instead of IP - possible?

Tags: networking, lan, nginx

I am sure the answer is pretty straight forward or already somewhere out there, but until now I was only able to find similar problems but not finding a solution for me.

I have NGINX installed and working on my local Server and can access & serve a webpage by its IP-address. Now I was wondering, instead of using the IP, is it possible to use some sort of domain name?

E.g.:

if I type "test.domain.com" into the browser it should open the page defined, but currently this only works via "192.168.1.99".

Just some additional notes:

- Server must be accessible only via LAN, no connectivity from the "outside"
- I pretty much followed this [Tutorial on Codeburst](https://codeburst.io/how-to-setup-nginx-for-react-a504f38f95ed) for the nginx set-up.
- Server & Page should be accessible from any device within the LAN, ideally without manipulating any of their hosts files?!

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: What's the lan run? You could possibly add custom entries to the DNS server...

Comment: Could you clarify what problems you're actually having? I mean, if you want a domain that points to the server, then get a domain and point it to the server...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: What do you mean by what's the LAN run? "normal" LAN config: Server + Switches/Routers + WAPs

Comment: @grawity: The problem is, that I don't want /need a public domain - this page should work within the LAN even if no Internet Access is available. I just would like to avoid using the IP address and instead using a more "memorable" name - like "test.domain.com".

Comment: Well, a consumer router has a DHCP and DNS server - and you might be able to set hostnames there

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Thanks for that, this actually works! I put the hostname on the Router. Still wondering though if there is also no way to do that with NGINX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its worth thinking of your network as a bunch of different services, that just happen to work together.

So, a consumer router can be a DHCP server (optionally - giving out IPs), a firewall (forwarding packets), and a DNS server. You basically need to set the DNS server that your systems are querying to resolve the hostname to the IP. In reality, the "internet" has servers which talk to each other to tell where something resolves, and this works to propagate things across.

Your *web* server can take a request and send content based on what the hostname is (virtualhosts), but unless the host knows *where* to ask, the packets won't get there.

Comment: Understood-
I was just under the impression that the Webserver could somehow act as a DNS-Server due to the fact, that it was local/within the LAN only... But this solution works for me! Thanks.